# How do I add co-hosts to my page's event?

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages, facebook-events

I manage a Facebook Page which organizes events now and then. One event is being organized together with a different Page, managed by different people. I would like to set up Facebook to register both Pages as the event hosts. So that both can invite their fans and such. How do I do this?

I already found the canonical Facebook [answer](https://www.facebook.com/help/501279386703858) to this question, but somehow I do not see the co-host option anywhere...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that it is relatively easy, as long as you remember one thing that Facebook does not mention:

**Use Facebook as your personal you!**

Summarizing all steps:

1. Use the full desktop interface, no app
2. Create the event, published or not
3. Make sure to use Facebook as your personal you: click the down triangle at the top right and click your human name, **not** the Page's name
4. Find the event
5. Edit it
6. At **Co-Hosts**, add any *person* you know managing the other Page
7. Ask that person to follow the same steps (instead of creating the event s/he should **attend** it)
8. Ask that person to add the other Page as co-host

The event will now automatically be shown on the other Page's list of events. Anyone managing the other Page can now invite their fans.

Both Pages will be shown as organizers, at least sometimes. In some situations however, only the 'relevant' Page is shown: the one the user happens to like.

Note that Page events can have persons as co-hosts, but not the other way around: personal events can only have persons as co-hosts.